# Multidimensional java array issues

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

New and confused about how to print a table type of scoreboard with scores in it as they come in. This is how I'm starting;

```
public class Table {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        table();
    }

    public static void table() {
        int[][] list = new int[4][4];
        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + "      ");
            // i++;
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(("   ") + (list[3][2] = 3)); // target location

        for (int j = 1; j <= 4; j++)
            System.out.println(j);
    }
}
```

But how would I get the `list[3][2] = 3` to print where I set it; for instance list[i][j]=4. In other words, how do I print the new values inside the matrix at different locations?

Answer (score 1):

This will print the all possibilities in array.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
     list[i][j] = something  // filling
     System.out.println(list[i][j]); //getting
   }
 }
```

And take care that you are just declared the array not filling it. Before accessing them fill it.

More over there is a chance to get  Out of Bounds exception use `<` instead `<=` (*Noticed that you are using i=1, Then it's fine*)

Comment: Using `for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) { }` is only fine if you use `i - 1` in the loop, which would be a little bit illogical though.